# What is the best configuration for counters logs in Windows?

Tags: windows, perfmon, performancecounter

I am going to program a little application for check any bottlenecks which might be in my Windows systems. So that, I think to use Performance Monitor to collect data from Disk, memory, network and CPU counters and save these data in a file .csv
Now I am wondering: what is the best choice for collect data?
My idea is to collect anything in one file, with all data log of counters, every 15 seconds, becouse a shorter detection might loads uselessly the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At work I have used [Performance Monitor by Hexagora](http://www.hexagora.com/en_dw_davperf.asp) (its freeware) -  don't know if you can record the result however as I have only ever used the graphical representations.

I have also used the Windows Performance Monitor, outputting .csv files (as you are doing), but if you are collecting alot of data I find it very messy.

A guide for best practice when monitoring performance from Microsoft is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_mpmonperf_09.mspx?mfr=true). I often use this as a guide, hope this is helpful.

Comment: The tool you suggest me doesn't work well, but the guide is very usefull. Thanks!

Comment: @maxim - sorry to tool is not what you were looking for, but I am glad the guide was useful.